# Download Folders with Go

Tags: authentication, go, go-modules

I am using Grab, a Go package for downloading files from the internet. I am able to download files into a directory using:

```
resp, err := grab.Get(".", "http://www.golang-book.com/public/pdf/gobook.pdf")
if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println("Download saved to", resp.Filename)
```

How can I download an entire folder that has sub-folders with files from a link that requires authentication using this package or any other alternative.

Comment: HTTP has no mechanism for doing that directly, and since `http://www.golang-book.com/public/pdf/` doesn't give a directory listing but a page, there is no way to do what you're asking for exactly. The closest you could get would be crawling the page and links and filtering for the file type(s) you want to download.

Comment: if you are using `https://github.com/cavaliergopher/grab` you should be able to do it !! However, I see the URL seems to non existing now, can you verify once?